# SQL Server 2008 R2 installation issue on Windows7 64 bit machine

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-2008, windows-7-x64

Earlier I was using Visual Studio 2005 and SQL Server 2005 for my desktop application. Later we are trying to migrate from SQL Server 2005 to 2008 R2 so we had taken .Net 3.5, Windows Installer 4.5, SQL Server 2008 R2 as a prerequisites and created exe file successfully.

I tested this application on Windows XP, Windows 7 - 32 bit machines with no issues but while installing this on a Windows 7 - 64 bit machine it is getting failed to install.

Can anybody help on this?

Comment: It would help to know the **complete and exact** error message you're getting! We can't see and read your screen, you know ....

Comment: for errors check the windows eventlog.

Answer (score 0):

Have you compiled your application to support 64-bit?